# Using Netis WF2123 Wifi Adapter on an AMD64 Ubuntu System

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wifi

I'm having trouble getting the drivers for a Netis WF2123 wifi adapter to work under Linux Mint 17 (effectively Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) 64-bit.

As it turns out the drivers are not available in any binary version from Netis nor do there appear to be any packages in this distro. Netis provides the full driver source, a script for compiling and installing the driver, and a guide for manual compilation and installation. However, running either the script, which basically just extracts the source tarball and runs `make`, or running `make` manually in the source directory triggers an error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/arch/x86/Makefile:113: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `Wf2123'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

It also appears that it was only set up to compile for 32-bit, which I thought might be a problem, if the running kernels were 64-bit native.

I am running these commands as root, as the provided script requests root permissions for `make`.

I have downloaded drivers for the chip (RTL8192CU) from Realtek, but they also trigger errors (different ones, though, I'll look more into them). Kernels.org apparently has support for this chip in their backports, but I'm not quite sure how to go about installing one of these backports.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You should almost never be running `make` as root (save for `install` rules). Also, please consider adding real error output to this question (verbatim).

Comment: 1. it's almost always a bad idea to use hardware that requires a custom driver sourced from the manufacturer.  it's barely tolerable when it's unusual hardware, but not when it's commodity hardware like a wifi adaptor.  2. same for the rtl8192cu drivers.  a driver for this chip has been in the mainline kernel for several versions now - use that (upgrade your kernel if necessary) instead of the realtek-provided driver.  3. wifi adaptors that use the `rtl8192cu` driver are notoriously unreliable -  chuck it out and replace with one that uses an atheros chip & driver, such as `ath9k` or `ath10k`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the adapter works without installing any special drivers. I just assumed they would be needed. Just found this out. Sorry!